# Tomcat 8 installation in SUSE linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssl

```
I completed the basic setup of Tomcat 8 on SUSE, but now I want to move to production setup which uses APR, so I installed the following packages in the same order

1) OpenSSL lib. --[/usr/local/ssl/]
2) APR lib --[/usr/local/apr/]
3) compiled and installed libtcnative using the above packages.

The installation did not show any error report, but when  i start tomcat using startup.sh, this error is generated in log file

"Failed to initialize the SSLEngine. org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 70023: This function
has not been implemented on this platform at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.initialize(Native Method) "

and also this error goes away when i modify the aprlifecycle listener in server.xml like

"Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="off" />"

but then tomcat wont start with https://____:port no

Can somebody please let me know what am i doing wrong or are there any steps that i am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rohit
```

This is the output of ./config.nice

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking for working mkdir -p... yes
    Tomcat Native Version: 1.1.28
    checking for chosen layout... tcnative
    checking for APR... yes
      setting CC to "gcc"
      setting CPP to "gcc -E"
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking for JDK location (please wait)... /usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40
    checking Java platform... checking Java platform... 
    checking for sablevm... NONE
      adding "-I/usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
    checking os_type directory...  linux
      adding "-I/usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/include/linux" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
    checking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/local/ssl/lib and /usr/local/ssl/include
    checking OpenSSL library version... ok
    checking for OpenSSL DSA support... yes
      adding "-I/usr/local/ssl/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
      setting TCNATIVE_LDFLAGS to "-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
      adding "-DHAVE_OPENSSL" to CFLAGS
      setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to ""
      setting TCNATIVE_LIBS to " /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt  -lpthread -ldl"
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating tcnative.pc
    config.status: creating Makefile
    config.status: executing default commands
    $$:/u/naskulwa/Desktop/Tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.28-src/jni/native> ./config.status 
    config.status: creating tcnative.pc
    config.status: creating Makefile
    config.status: executing default commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you built libtcnative without SSL support. Go back and check the contents of config.nice to see exactly what was used.

Comment: Its using the same path I supplied during installation, but just to be sure, the actual libs are at /usr/local/apr/lib and /usr/local/ss/lib, but i gave the path till /usr/local/apr and same for openssl, is it this path thats causing the problem?

Comment: Are you sure those are the paths you used? There appears to be a typo in the SSL path.

Comment: Thanks, got it solved when i installed aprlib and openssl using zypper,and then while building libtcnative i only gave the path of apr lib not of openssl, I dont understand why it was not working when I compiled lib apr and openssl from source and installed them

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble, there are two things that re important and i forgot about them 1)build openssl package with --enable-shared flag and 2) check the compatibility of tomcat and openssl versions.